# Ionic Navigation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, navigation, ionic-view

I have Ionic 1 app where I have folder templates (home.html, menu.html, about.html..). The problem is in index.hmtl I have code :

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

This code run ionic navigation on every page. The question is how can i remove navigation from pages that I want to be without navigation? I tried hide-nav-bar="true"- this hide navigation but I can still open it with swipe.
My app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
      }
    }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

Controler.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/home.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);

    // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
    // code if using a login system
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeLogin();
    }, 1000);
  };
})

.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.playlists = [
    { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
    { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
    { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
    { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
  ];
})

.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in your app.js file while configuring the states.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider  
    .state('home', {
     url: '/home',
     templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    })
   .state('app', {
     url: '/app',
     abstract: true,
     templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
     controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
});
```